# SQL Server Management Studio Integrated in to Sql Server 2005 Enterprise setup?

Tags: sql-server

does `SQL Server Management Studio` integrated in to `SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition`?

if i am installing **SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition** than i required to install `SSME` separately?

Please help Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management Studio comes with the SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition suite.  It's part of management tools.  You have the option NOT to install it, but that is not recommended.